# Drupal Views field display html entities

Tags: drupal, view

I have a problem with the Drupal 6 Views Module : it displays the html as plain text instead of interpreting it ([see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7GWm.png)).

Is there an option to show the rendered html?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the the field of the node to show html, at the moment it's set to raw text.

Comment: Ok, I have to do this in Node field Configuration, or in View Field configuration ? Because node seems accept HTML. There is a WYSIWYG editor.. strange

Comment: You have to do it in both.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED ! The solution was in field node options.

In the text processing option : you have to choose FILTERED TEXT instead of RAW TEXT

Comment: Next time instead of posting it as an answer of your own, you could just accept the answer.